# facet multiple fields on search query set

Tags: django, field, django-haystack, facet

How can I choose multiple fields for faceting on a `SearchQuerySet` ? The Example in the [Documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html) shows fow to facet on a single field.

> sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('author')

Say, I have multiple fields that I want to facet on like , `author`, `location`, `score` ? How would I do that ?

Currently, if I use the above example from the documentation, it works as expected, But how do I implement multiple fields for faceting on a `SearchQuerySet` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call facet method multiple times on the queryset for each field. You can do something like this.

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet()
facet_list = ('author', 'location', 'age')
for item in facet_list:
    sqs = sqs.facet(item)
```

Comment: one of those "Why didn't I think of this !!" moments !